# Instantiate object inside another class not main method

Tags: c#, oop

Below I have created a simple class named 'Staff'. When I try to instantiate a new staff object in the main method, everything works perfect. Why does it work in the main method, but not in my farse method "Frog"?

```
class staff
{
    //Fields
    private string nameOfStaff;
    private const int hourlyRate = 30;
    private int hWorked;

    //Properties
    public int HoursWorked
    {
        get
        {
            return hWorked;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
                hWorked = value;
            else
                hWorked = 0;
        }
    }


    //Methods
    public void PrintMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calculating Pay...");
    }

    public int CalculatePay()
    {
        PrintMessage();

        int staffPay;
        staffPay = hWorked * hourlyRate;

        if (hWorked > 0)
            return staffPay;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public int CalculatePay(int bonus, int allowances)
    {
        PrintMessage();
        if (hWorked > 0)
            return hWorked * hourlyRate + bonus + allowances;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name of Staff = " + nameOfStaff + ", hourlyRate = " + hourlyRate + ", hWorked = " + hWorked;
    }

    //Constructors
    public staff(string name)
    {
        nameOfStaff = name;
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + nameOfStaff);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
    }

    public staff(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        nameOfStaff = firstName + " " + lastName;
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + nameOfStaff);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Instanciating an Object
        int pay;
        staff staff1 = new staff("Peter");
        staff1.HoursWorked = 160;
        pay = staff1.CalculatePay(1000, 400);
        Console.WriteLine("Pay = {0}", pay);
 }

 class frog 

 {
  // Why can't I instantiate a staff member here?
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't? What are you attempting to do? What error are you getting?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't implement and instantiate a `staff` typed field?

Comment: Hmmm -- I can. Are you sure you haven't marked your class static or som,ething? What error are you getting and where?

Comment: Instead of just stating that you "cannot instantiate a staff member here", show us the actual code you tried to use, and the error message you got when you tried.

Comment: I think you guys are diving a bit deeper. When I create a new staff object in the main method I am able to access the fields, properties and methods of staff. When I put the code that is in the main method in class frog, I am unable to access the same features.

Comment: @azurefrog the code in its entirety is there. If you copy the code from the main method into class frog, you will see that it won't compile

Comment: "the code that is in the main method" contains a lot of statements that aren't instantiation of a member variable.  Are you trying to add statements outside of a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, probably, want to move the code from `main` into the `frog`s *constructor*, where you can access fields, methods, properties:

```
 class frog 
 {
   public staff Staff {get; set;} 

   public frog() {
     Staff = new staff("Peter");

     // Now do everything you like with the Staff  
     Staff.HoursWorked = 160;  
   }  
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a simple difference between your answer and what I've provided below?

Comment: I'd rather extract computation `int pay =Staff1.CalculatePay(1000, 400);` into separate method; then I'll override `ToString()` for `string.format(Pay = {0}", pay);`.

Comment: The difference is that you can freely access fields, methods, properties within a method's scope; in this particular case a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe I didn't ask the question correctly (because I didn't know the answer) but I was able to figure it out...

```
 class frog
{
    static void newStaff()
    {
        staff staff4 = new staff;
        staff4.HoursWorked
    }
}
```

I'm not positive what the static void newStaff() does, but it allows the code to compile. Obviously new here trying to learn..

Answer (score 0):

When you try to instantiate a new object from a class, it needs to done either inside a method or the constructor of the class.

The object can be created only when it is called through a method, So instantiating it outside of a method or a constructor wouldn't work.